# Is there a comma required in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, commas, prepositional-phrases, dependent-clause, non-restrictive

Consider the following.

> He participated in one of the most challenging swimming competitions SwimFest-X in countryname-Y, which facilitated his success in Z.

or should there be a comma before SwimFest-X?

> He participated in one of the most challenging swimming competitions, SwimFest-X in countryname-Y, which facilitated his success in Z.

Why or why not?

Comment: OT; change "the one of most" to "one of the most".

Comment: what is "which" supposed to refer to in your sentences?  Swimfest?  His participation?

Comment: @Thruston fixed the type about "the one of most" in the OP. Should be "one of the most".  "which" is supposed to refer to SwimFest-X and it occurred in countryname-Y.

Comment: Note that in US English, it's common to use a comma before *which*; otherwise we use *that*. In UK English, I don't think there is that distinction. So, people from different regions might answer this differently. (However, comma or not, using *that* in this sentence wouldn't work unless it were rephrased.) A comma before *which* always sounds better to me.

Comment: @JasonBassford comma before "which" isn't the issue, if there should be one before "swimfest-X" is.

Comment: As you allude to in a comment under one of the answers, it depends entirely on if you want the information about countryname-Y to be restrictive or nonrestrictive. There is no *right* answer. It's up to you (or the author) to decide what you want to convey. It's not a question or right or wrong but intention.

Comment: @JasonBassford i'm not sure if restrictive phrase here would apply? E.g. Is this correct without a comma before Model-X? "He bought one of the fastest cars Model-X of Ferrari, which can go up to speeds of 200mph"

Comment: Actually, now that I look at the construction of these sentences more closely, they would both need to be modified slightly in order to allow for the restrictive. The easiest way of doing so is to just use a colon. *He bought one of the fastest cars: the Model-X of Ferrari, which can go up to speeds of 200 mph.*

Comment: Since this is an appositive construction, I'd say it would require a comma before Swimfest. But this would apply only if you're referring to Swimfest as one of the most challenging competitions anywhere (you've explained in your comment that this is your meaning). If you are speaking only of events in one country, however, then a clear way to write that would be: _...participated in one of the most challenging swimming competitions in country Y, SwimFest-X, which facilitated his success..._

Comment: Balanced offsetting punctuation is required round a medial parenthetical (here, a more rigorously specifying appositive): << He participated in one of the most challenging swimming competitions –  SwimFest-X in Yland – which facilitated his success in Z. >> Brackets, 2 dashes, or 2 commas. Zero punctuation doesn't work here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth but if "in Yland" is adverbial, describing the location of his participation, then you'd have "He participated in one of the most challenging swimming competitions, SwimFest-X, in Yland, which facilitated his success in Z."  Analogous: "She bought a sandwich at one of the most ubiquitous supermarkets, XMart, on Y Street, which allowed her to Z."  It's a lot of commas.  Using brackets or dashes instead would indeed help.

Comment: Putting a full stop after countryname-Y would be my preference.

Answer (score 1):

'SwimFest-X' is apposite to, and specifies, 'one of the most challenging swimming competitions'. Their juncture [calls for a colon](http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/colonandsemi/colon).

**'... one of the most challenging swimming competitions: SwimFest-X ...'**

Comment: I voted thus up for recognising that Swimfest-X is in apposition and should have a comma before and after it. The question of if and why there is a comma before "which" was not asked.

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are intelligible; however, it is the second one that makes more sense for the information in this sentence.

> He participated in one of the most challenging swimming competitions SwimFest-X in
>   countryname-Y, which facilitated his success in Z.

In this first version, the comma is used to separate an independent clause from a dependent clause.
The independent clause is, "He participated in one of the most challenging swimming competitions SwimFest-X in countryname-Y." This clause is independent because it has its own subject ("he") and verb ("participated"), and is a complete thought. Therefore, it can stand alone as a sentence.
The dependent clause is, "which facilitated his success in Z." While this clause does contain its own subject and verb -- with "which" acting as the subject (and pronoun) and "facilitated" being the verb -- it does not form a complete thought. The word "which" refers to the the swimming competitions mentioned in the previous clause, but you cannot tell what "which" means by the dependent clause alone. It is in this way that the clause does not form a complete thought, thus rendering it dependent.

> He participated in one of the most challenging swimming competitions, SwimFest-X in 
>   countryname-Y, which facilitated his success in Z.

The second version you have included is more like a main sentence with a dependent clause sandwiched in the middle. The main sentence is, "He participated in one of the most challenging swimming competitions which facilitated his success in Z." The dependent clause in the middle is, "SwimFest-X in countryname-Y." To have this information sectioned off with commas, as you do in this example, means that you can completely remove the phrase from the sentence and it still make sense. (This happens where I typed the main sentence previously.) Separating the information with commas is similar to separating it with parentheses or dashes. Generally, you can pull this information out without decreasing coherency, since it is used to elaborate on the main information of the sentence.

For your specific case, since "SwimFest-X in countryname-Y" is elaborating the object of the sentence ("swimming competitions"), the second version makes more sense; elaborating information can be set apart with punctuation to show that it is an additional descriptor, unnecessary for understanding the whole sentence.

Comment: I think I understand the reason for comma before "which", but whether there "should" be a comma before SwimFest-X I think depends on what intends to be communicated, i.e. if "swimfestX in country-Y" is a restrictive clause for "one of the most challenging swimming competitions" or not-restrictive. I think it's restrictive because "one of the most challenging swim competitions" alone doesn't tell you if it's swimfest-X or not, it could be any of several. If restrictive, there can't/shouldn't be comma before SwimFest-X.

Answer (score -3):

Q: He participated in one of the most challenging swimming competitions, SwimFest-X in countryname-Y, which facilitated his success in Z.

**A: He participated in one of the most challenging swimming competitions. SwimFest-X was held at __________ . This facilitated his success in Z.**

(alt)

**He participated in SwimFest-X, which facilitated his success in Z. SwimFest-X is one of the most challenging swimming competitions and was held in countryname-Y.**